# How to let R know a function is not an S3 method?

Tags: r, function, methods

If I define a function called

```
log.foo = function(foo){
  log(foo)
}
```

then R will think it is a S3 method. How can I tell R log.foo() is not the S3 method for the class foo. (In fact, class foo does not exist.)

Or do I just have to rename my function?

Comment: You don't need to do anything if there is no registered class named `foo` and even if there is one, you still may not need to. What errors are you getting? Id you had a class named foo then objects of that class would get returned as log()-ed values when you executed `log(obj)`

Comment: this should not cause any problem. Also amazon-s3 is quite different from R S3 methods.

Comment: Thank you both. The trouble is when I try to build a package including such a function, I got the warning "checking S3 generic/method consistency ... WARNING"

Comment: Well if you want to avoid the package compiler warning, which is a good thing to avoid, then use `log_foo` as the name.

Comment: I fully agree.  Function (and variable) naming rules is a long-standing, ahem, controversy in the `R` community, but since `function.class` is the expected way to define methods, it's really much better in the long run not to name your functions with dots. Personally I like `functionFoo` but as I said, tastes vary :-)

Comment: It seems I should change the function name, then that's what I will do. (I somehow feel that it is possible to tell whether a function is a S3 method, even when there is dot in the function name.) Thanks.

Comment: You might be confusing methods with object classes here. A function can return an S3 or an S4 object.